# How to display param's name correctly from Kotlin high order function in java

Tags: java, kotlin

Here's a download function written by Kotlin, in order to know the download progress
and statements like downloading or failed or success, I've created a callback named 'listener' with two parameters.

Kotlin :

```
object Downloader{
    fun download( url:String, listener:((progress:Int, status:Int )->Unit) ){
        //...
    }
}
```

Java :

```
Downloader.download( "TargetUrl" , new Function2<Integer, Integer, Unit>() {
       @Override
       public Unit invoke(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
           //..
       }
});
```

As you can see in java code, we can't tell what's 'integer' and 'interger2' stand for.
My question is how can I keep these names in java?

Expected Java code:

```
Downloader.download( "TargetUrl" , new Function2<Integer, Integer, Unit>() {
       @Override
       public Unit invoke(Integer progress, Integer status) {
           //..
       }
});
```

BIG THANKS !!!

Comment: The parameter names are not part of the signature of the function. You are free to call them whatever you want. You cannot force them to be called progress and status.

Comment: So what's generating the Java code for you?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it's the AutoComplete in android studio 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the caller know what those parameters mean you can consider:

1. Document them properly.
2. Create an interface as an alternative.

```kotlin
interface Listener {
  fun onChanged(progress: Int, status: Int)
}

object Downloader{
  fun download( url:String, listener: Listener) { ... }
}
```

You can than call it from Java (though the caller could still change those parameter names).

```java
download("url", new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(int progress, int status) {
    // ...      
  }
});
```